# How to import images with a csv-import of items?

Tags: csv, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In the beginig, I'm very new in this theme. So, I have about 1000 items' images named as .jpg and I have csv-file with items' details. I can import the list of items without any problems in my prestashop 1.6.0.9, but how can I connect csv-import with that group of images which called-by-reference connected with reference of items inside of CSV-file? If I add the image by hand into item I see it as /img/p/{1}{2}{3}.jpg if the reference number as 123 but I don't understand where this settings are (perhaps mod_rewrite issue) and how to make import images automatically. If you have the best practices of that or can image about I say, please give me any ideas what I have to do. Thank you all for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The  /img/p/{1}{2}{3}.jpg is when the image is treated by Prestashop, you don't need to do that to import your pictures.
Just complete your CSV file with the proper image URL. Ex : http://www.exemple.com/images/mypicture.jpg
Prestashop will automatically change it to the p/1/2/1/x.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The CSV import function allows you to import images. You just need to specify the image URLs, comma seperated, in the CSV and Prestashop will import the images from those URLs in the proper file location.

Answer (score 0):

In prestashp CSV import you can finde product import simple file like this

https://dropmefiles.com/McJO3

Where http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/2/3/23.jpg you can change to link of you needed image like link below

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToZGEWvIBFgCiona6d74FtVthl4lkdJg3d61SGy-UCf4qFuDLD

You can use more than one image. For this you need separate them by coma

Comment: such as http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/12345.jpg, http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/9876.jpg or such as  http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/12345.jpg,9876.jpg ?

Comment: You can add any image what you need to download. But this must be real link to this image. It can be on your host, or some image host or other site

Comment: But not in this way localhost/prestashop/img/p/12345.jpg,9876.jpg

Comment: You need to add it in this way: http:\\somesite.com\blabla1.jpg, http:\\somesite.com\blabla2.jpg